# Elasticsearch Edge NGram tokenizer higher score when word begins with n-gram

Tags: elasticsearch, search, n-gram

Suppose there is the following mapping with Edge NGram Tokenizer:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "standard"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "symbol"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "tag": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the following documents are indexed:

```
POST /tag/tag/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"name" : "HITS FIND SOME"}
{"index":{}}
{"name" : "TRENDING HI"}
{"index":{}}
{"name" : "HITS OTHER"}
```

Then searching

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "HI"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yields all with the same score, or `TRENDING - HI` with a score higher than one of the others.

How can it be configured, to show with a higher score the entries that actually start with the searcher n-gram? In this case, `HITS FIND SOME` and `HITS OTHER` to have a higher score than `TRENDING HI`; at the same time `TRENDING HI` should be in the results.

Highlighter is also used, so the given solution shouldn't mess it up.

The highlighter used in query is:

```
 "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      ">"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "name": {}
    }
  }
```

Using this with `match_phrase_prefix` messes up the highlighting, yielding `<H><I><T><S> FIND SOME` when searching only for `H`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must understand how elasticsearch/lucene analyzes your data and calculate the search score.

**1. Analyze API**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_testing_analyzers.html this will show you what elasticsearch will store, in your case:

```
T / TR / TRE /.... TRENDING / / H / HI
```

**2. Score**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

The bool query is often used to build complex query where you need a particular use case. Use `must` to filter document, then `should` to score. A common use case is to use different analyzers on a same field (by using the keyword `fields` in the mapping, you can analyze a same field differently).

**3. dont mess highlight**

According the doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#specify-highlight-query

You can add an extra query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
            "must" : [
                        {
          "match": {
            "name": "HI"
          }
        }
            ],
      "should": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": "HI"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
     "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      ">"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "name": {
                "highlight_query": {
                        "match": {
            "name": "HI"
          }
                }
            }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case you could add a `match_phrase_prefix` term to your query, which does prefix match on the last term in the text:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "HI"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "name": "HI"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The `match` term will match on all three results, but the `match_phrase_prefix` won't match on `TRENDING HI`. As a result, you'll get all three items in the results, but `TRENDING HI` will appear with a lower score.

Quoting the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html):

> The match_phrase_prefix query is a poor-man’s autocomplete[...] For better solutions for search-as-you-type see the completion suggester and Index-Time Search-as-You-Type.

On a side note, if you're introducing that `bool` query, you'll probably want to look at the [`minimum_should_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) option, depending on the results you want.

Comment: But I need `TRENDING HI` as a result; just with a lower score.

Comment: @m3th0dman the overall results are a combination of matching results for each term, so `TRENDING HI` will appear in the results, and it will appear with a lower score. Edited the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately this messes up the highlighter.

Comment: @m3th0dman that's a new element. Could you give some more details on how you're doing the highlighting, and what you mean exactly by it being "messed up"?

Comment: Sure; thanks. 
I modified the question to include the highlighter. With `match_phrase_prefix` it returns something like `<H><I><T><S> FIND SOME` when searching only for `H`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for this problem is to use [multifields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html). They allow for indexing of the same data from your source document in different ways. In your case you could index the `name` field as default `text`, then as `ngrams` and also as [edgengrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html). Then the query would have to be a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) comparing with all those different `fields`.

The final score of documents is composed of the match value for each one. Those matches are also called `signals`, signalling that there is a match between the query and the document. The document with most signals matching gets the highest score.

In your case all documents would match the `ngram` `HI`. But only the `HITS FIND SOME` and the `HITS OTHER` document would get the `edgengram` additional score. This would give those two documents a boost and put them on top. The complication with this is that you have to make sure that the `edgengram` doesn't split on whitespaces, because then the `HI` at the end would get the same score as in the beginning of the document.

Here is an example mapping and query for your case:

```
PUT /tag/
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "edge_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "edge_tokenizer"
                },
                "kw_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "kw_tokenizer"
                },
                "ngram_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
                },
                "autocomplete_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "autocomplete_tokenizer",
                    "filter": [
                        "standard"
                    ]
                },
                "autocomplete_search": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "kw_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "edge_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 10
                },
                "ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 10,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ]
                },
                "autocomplete_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 10,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "symbol"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "tag": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "edge": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "edge_analyzer"
                        },
                        "ngram": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a query:

```
POST /tag/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                "function_score": {
                    "query": {
                        "match": {
                            "name.edge": {
                                "query": "HI"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "boost": "5",
                    "boost_mode": "multiply"
                }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name.ngram": {
                            "query": "HI"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "HI"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```