# Search as per the relevance in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

We are trying to apply a fuzzy search on zipcodes using following analyzer

```
PUT test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 40      
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "ngram",        
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 40
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "zipcode": {
        "type": "text",            
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample data in the index is as follows

```
PUT test_index/_doc/1
{ "zipcode": "01103" }

PUT test_index/_doc/2
{ "zipcode": "01104" }

PUT test_index/_doc/3
{ "zipcode": "11010" }

PUT test_index/_doc/4
{ "zipcode": "11016" }

PUT test_index/_doc/5
{ "zipcode": "11020" }

PUT test_index/_doc/6
{ "zipcode": "01107" }

PUT test_index/_doc/7
{ "zipcode": "11024" }

PUT test_index/_doc/8
{ "zipcode": "04110" }
```

Search query used on zipcode field is as follows :

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "zipcode": {
        "query": "110",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We expected the data to be returned as per the more relevant one which is :

```
11010
11020
11024
11016
01103
01104
01107
```

but the actual data is returned is in this order .How can we boost the documents starting from 110.. to appear first

```
{
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 0.45532414,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "11016"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.45532414,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "01103"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.2885665,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "11010"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 0.2885665,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "11020"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : 0.2885665,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "11024"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "8",
        "_score" : 0.2885665,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "04110"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.2885665,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "01104"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : 0.2885665,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "01107"
        }
      }
```

Following Query gives the order as expected but i am not sure which one should i use for my use case

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "zipcode": "110"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "zipcode": "110"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

vs

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix" : { "zipcode" : "110" }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for a prefix query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/query-dsl-prefix-query.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elasticsearch Edge NGram tokenizer higher score when word begins with n-gram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53238598/elasticsearch-edge-ngram-tokenizer-higher-score-when-word-begins-with-n-gram)

Comment: i tried using match_phrase_prefix and prefix approach ,both gave the expected result but which one is more suitable to use based on my use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a should clause with [prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) query. It will give higher score to documents which start with that prefix.

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "zipcode": {
              "query": "110",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "zipcode": "110"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 5.0441885,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "11010"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 5.0441885,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "11016"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 5.0441885,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "11020"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : 5.0441885,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "11024"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 3.0168114,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "01103"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 3.0168114,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "01104"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : 3.0168114,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "01107"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "8",
        "_score" : 0.18093312,
        "_source" : {
          "zipcode" : "04110"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: above query with should and prefix did not give the expected results ,but when i just used this {
  "query": {
    "prefix" : { "zipcode" : "110" }
  }
}  it bumped the zipcodes with 110 first .This seems to work like sql Like query and the score of all docs is set to 1 .Is that the correct way of handling such scenario

Comment: @amrit can you add the query you used. Returned documents and expected result

Comment: i edited my above query section  with 2 feedback comments that i tried ,1:  match_phrase_prefix with should 2: using prefix without should .my expected result is as follows    11010
11020
11024
11016
01103
01104
01107

Comment: if you want documents starting with 110 to appear first then should clause with match phrase